# Imprimir todo el vector por pantalla C++

Tags: c++

Buenas noches amigos. Nunca me he planteado esta operacion y no se como solucionarlo, resulta que tengo un vector al cual le he hecho una serie de operaciones pero necesito comprobar que la totalidad de ellas estan bien. La unica forma que se me ha ocurrido ha sido imprimir este vector por pantalla y comprarlas con la solucion original. El problema es que al devolverlo por pantalla se corta por la mitad y no puedo hacerlo

```
cout << "Principio" << endl;
for (i = 0; i < 756; i++)
{
    cout << vector[i] << " Numero " << i+1 << endl;
}
cout << auxi << endl;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No es que *se te corte*, es que llenas el *buffer* de la ventana de terminal, con lo que las primeras líneas se pierden. Dependiendo del emulador, puedes intentar aumentar las líneas de *buffer*. O, alternativamente, vuelca el *array* a un archivo y compruébalo ahí. O muestra solo X líneas, y haz una pausa (hasta pulsar una tecla, por ejemplo) antes de seguir.

Answer (score 1):

Eso es porque se llenó el buffer de la consola, podrías redirigir la salida estándar a un archivo de texto por consola:

```
./tuProgramaCompilado > salida.txt
```

O escribir los valores en un archivo directamente desde el código:

```
ofstream miArchivoDeTexto; // Declaro el archivo
miArchivoDeTexto.open ("salida.txt"); // Pongo una ruta
miArchivoDeTexto << "Principio" << endl;
for (i = 0; i < 756; i++)
{
    miArchivoDeTexto << vector[i] << " Numero " << i+1 << endl; // Escribo en el archivo
}
miArchivoDeTexto << auxi << endl;
miArchivoDeTexto.close(); // Cierro el archivo
```

Y listo, ahora podés ver todo el listado completo en el archivo `salida.txt`. Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Saludos!

Comment: Me gustaria agradeceros vuestros comentarios. Sin duda tengo que aprender a utilizar archivos. Yo di C hace 13 años y no lo he vuelto a tocarlo hasta ahora y por tanto tengo los conceptos de ficheros mas que olvidados. Sé que tendre que utilizar los ficheros en el futuro. Estoy documentandome antes de lanzar preguntas (intente lo que me dijiste pero debo de hacerlo mal porque no lo consigo). Al final la solucion ha sido un poquito mas chapucera, he sumado todo la matriz por columna y comparado con lo que me deberia de salir. No obstante muchisimas gracias me guardo tu comentario para el futuro

Comment: Hola! De nada colega, todo es práctica. Cuál es el error por el cual dices que no está funcionando?

Comment: `int main()

{
 int i,j;
 float k[756][3];
 ka(k);
 
 cout << k[755][0] << endl;

ofstream miArchivoDeTexto; // Declaro el archivo
miArchivoDeTexto.open ("C:\Users\T\Pictures"); // Pongo una ruta
miArchivoDeTexto << "Principio" << endl;
for (i = 0; i < 756; i++)
{
 for(j=0;j<3;j++)
 {
  miArchivoDeTexto << k[i] << " Numero " << i+1 << endl; // Escribo en el archivo
 }
    
}
miArchivoDeTexto.close(); // Cierro el archivo 
  
 cin.get();
 return 0;
}` El compilador devuelve 
aggregate 'std::ofstream miArchivoDeTexto' has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Comment: Agrégale la cabecera `#include <fstream>`

Comment: Avisanos si funcionó por favor

Answer (score 1):

### Implementa una pausa

Si el problema es que quieres leer todo sin que se te borre, puedes colocar un contador de lineas y una pausa después de algunas lineas

```
cout << "Principio" << endl;
int contador = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 756; i++)
{
    contador++;
    cout << vector[i] << " Numero " << i+1 << endl;
    if (contador >= 50) // lee 50 lineas
    { 
         contador = 0;
         while(getchar()!='\n'); // espera a que pulses enter
    }
}
cout << auxi << endl;
```

### Compara 2 archivos

La verdad no se si sea tu caso, pero lo dejo aquí por si acaso; pero si vuelcas toda la solución en un archivo como ha sugerido @Genarito y *tienes otro archivo* con la solución puedes hacer un programa que te compare ambos archivos, y te imprima los valores diferentes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream a;
    std::ifstream b;
    a.open("salida.txt");
    b.open("otro_archivo.txt");
    std::string str1;
    std::string str2;
    while (!a.eof())
    {
        a >> str1;
        b >> str2;
        if (str1.compare(str2)!=0) std::cout << str1 << std::endl;
    }
}
```

claro, esto sólo funciona si tienes otro archivo con el cual comparar.

Saludos

Comment: Tambien quiero agradecerte la respuesta (si hubiese multicita os habria citado a los dos) y por tanto siente el comentario mio anterior como tuyo. Muchas pero que muchas gracias. Me habeis intentado ayudar y de  hecho vuestra ayuda me va a servir en el futuro cuando llegue el momento y quiera meterme en el mundo de los ficheros.